# I want to update parentID of bulk of user using SoftLayer_User_Customer::editObjects. But facing issue as below

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to update parentID of bulk of users using SoftLayer_User_Customer::editObjects. But facing issue as below:

**{ message:
   { error: 'The property \'parentId\' is not valid for \'SoftLayer_User_CustomerArray\'.',
     code: 'SoftLayer_Exception_Public' },
  statusCode: 500 }**

My code is in nodejs

```
slClient
    .auth(slUserID, slApiKey)
    .path('User_Customer', childIds, 'editObjects')
    .parameters([{"parentId":parentID}])
    .put()
    .then(res => {
        resolve(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });
```

Here childIds is array of Softlayer IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SoftLayer_User_Customer::editObjects](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/editObjects/) method doesn't require an InitParameter in the header, so I recommend to remove **childIds** in the path.

The ID of each user you want to edit must to be in the parameters section like the sample below:

```
{
    "parameters":[
        [
            {
                "id": 1111111,         <----- user id you want to edit
                "parentId": 6666666    <----- the new parent id
            },
            {
                "id": 2222222,
                "parentId": 6666666
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:
Here aInput is Array of JSON object which has details of SL IDs. I am saving only ID of those SL IDs in my JSON obejct as shown below.

```
    let childIds = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < aInput.length; i++) 
    {
            var myObj = new Object();
            myObj.id = aInput[i].id;
            myObj.parentId = parentID;
            childIds.push(myObj);
    }

    console.log(childIds);
    slClient
    .auth(slUserID, slApiKey)
    .path('User_Customer','editObjects')
    .parameters([childIds])
    .put()
    .then(res => {
        resolve(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });
```